# How to add more rating / color actions in a menu?

Tags: gui-design, menu

It was just released a new beta version of an Image Manager program on which I work ([XnViewMP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) for conformity) in which (among other things) the program allow the user to rate the images with a classical 5-star/coloring system which is shown in several areas of the program - toolbars, right-click (sub)menus - like this:

[image: XnViewMP current rating menu]

However the program provides more functionality through its customizable shortcuts allowing an **"... and move to next image"** sibling for each action above. For example, as you see above, there exists an **'Excellent rating'** action in the menu. However there exists also an **'Rate Excellent and move to next image'** in the shortcuts list but nowhere in menus.

*How can we put these 12 **"... and move to next image"** siblings easily available and discoverable for the user's mouse (in the menus etc.) without cluttering too much the user interface?*

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to provide a shortcut for each variant?

I would have that thought that your users mainly fall into two classes, *those that want to rate and skip to the next*, and *those that want to rate only*. The third class of *those that want to rate and sometimes move to the next* seems like a much smaller subset.

So instead why not add a single setting to your application *Move to next image after rating* and provide them with a way to way to toggle it easily. Maybe you could just add a check box in your menu directly under the ratings so that those who do want to switch can access it simply, and possibly even add a shortcut for that?